# Sequence contains no elements handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

My API has a lot of db calls so I need to handle practically every database call with `FirstOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, but is there a way to do it better then

```cs
if (user == null) return NotFound();
```

every time I want to retrieve User row from database?

Comment: use caching https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/3-ways-to-improve-performance-using-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-application/

Comment: r u meaning a lot in same action or a lot in a lot actions

Comment: @spzvtbg a lot of db calls in a lot of api routes, and i want to handle them in one action filter, but i cant catch it for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `IAsyncActionFilter`, my code:

```cs
public class SampleAsyncActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var result = await next();
        if (result.Exception == null || result.Exception.GetType() != typeof(InvalidOperationException)) return;
        result.Result = new NotFoundObjectResult("Row was not found");
        result.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

And `ConfigureServices` function

```cs
services.AddMvc(f => f.Filters.Add(new SampleAsyncActionFilter()));
```